# how grab max value of a column based on information in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna grab the maximum value of column score for common values in first column

example

```
f    score
A    4
B    5
A    6
A    0
C    1
C    4
Y    2
```

output

```
f    score
A    6
B    5
C    4
Y    2
```

explanation: the max score when `f[i]==A` is 6 and when `f[i]==C` is 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html):

```
df.groupby('f', as_index=False, sort=False).max()
```

output:

```
   f  score
0  A      6
1  B      5
2  C      4
3  Y      2
```

*NB. depending on the use case, the `sort=False` option in `groupby` can be set to keep the original order of the groups (which doesn't make a difference with this dataset).

Comment: Might want sort=False as well if `f` isn't already or shouldn't be sorted.

Comment: Sure, I added a note about it :)